# Import-Csv and creating hashtable failing

Tags: csv, powershell

My CSV file has employee data and each person gets 2 codes, one for login and one for their positionID. To find their manager, I need to lookup the Reports to PositionID table as a cross reference. The problem I'm having is when I use `Import-Csv`, the first user in the file is terminated and the main login ID is removed from the file. I think that's why the following hash table fails with "Index operation failed; the array index evaluated to null"?

I tried

```
$csvData = Get-Content -Path $Maincsv | Select-Object -Skip 2 |
           Out-String | ConvertFrom-Csv
```

But this fails as well. How can I make adjustments to correctly build my table so it doesn't crash?

```
$csvData = Import-Csv "C:\My.csv"
$PIDTable = @{}
$csvData | ForEach-Object {
    $PIDTable[$_."Position ID"] = $_
}
```

Data:

```
PersonID   Position ID Legal First Name    Reports To Position ID
        YQM000051   DIANE           YQM000076
S9999991    YQM000052   CHARISSE        YQM000076
S9999992    YQM000052   CHARISSE        YQM000076
s9999993    YQM000052   CHARISSE        YQM000076
s9999994    YQM000076   Bob         YQM000071
```

So, trying to cross reference the PersonID from "Reports To Position ID" so that a PersonID could be found for someone's manager Position ID. Sorry for messy format. But can the blank PersonID at the start, mess the array up?

Comment: could this be solved by adding an if statement? `if ($_."position id" -notmatch '^(?:\s+)?$') {...`

Comment: To be honest, there shouldn't be any need to create the hashtable at all. Could you show a sample of your data?

Comment: Does your CSV have a header/labels on the first row?  If not, use the `-header` switch on ConvertFrom-Csv or Import-Csv.  Otherwise, the first row is considered to be the header, which I suspect is why "the first user in the file is terminated."

Comment: @EBGreen headers and data similar to this;                                        SID        Position ID First Name Reports To Position ID
             YQM000051 DIANE  YQM000076
S99999888 YQM000052 CHARISSE  YQM000076

Comment: SID  Position ID Legal First Name  Reports To Position ID
  YQM000051 DIANE   YQM000076
S0182719 YQM000052 CHARISSE  YQM000076 Formatting in this box sucks...

Comment: I may have to close this since I can't format the data to show you guys?

Comment: @MarcGel please [edit] your question, add your data, format them as code.

Comment: Sorry, recently edited. Thanks.

Comment: I have no idea? Today, the code above is working! I tested this successfully just now. $PIDTable = @{}

 Import-csv $ADPcsv | ForEach-Object {
    $PIDTable[$_.'Position ID'] = $_
}

Foreach ($Row in (Import-csv $ADPcsv)) {

$Manager = $Row.'Reports To Position ID'

        If ($PIDTable.ContainsKey($Manager)) { 

        $UserManager = $PIDTable[$Manager].'St Identification SID'

Write-Output (""+$Row.'St Identification SID'+" reports to "+$Manager+" "+$UserManager+"")}}

Answer (score 0):

Your data appears to be tab-separated, not comma-separated. `Import-Csv` expects data to be comma-separated unless you specify a different delimiter via the parameter `-Delimiter`. Since you didn't do that the cmdlet reads the file into data structures like this:

```
{ "PersonID   Position ID Legal First Name    Reports To Position ID": "        YQM000051   DIANE           YQM000076" }
{ "PersonID   Position ID Legal First Name    Reports To Position ID": "S9999991    YQM000052   CHARISSE        YQM000076" }
...
```

rather than the intended data structures:

```
{
  "PersonID": ""
  "Position ID": "YQM000051"
  "Legal First Name": "DIANE"
  "Reports To Position ID": "YQM000076"
}
{
  "PersonID": "S9999991"
  "Position ID": "YQM000052"
  "Legal First Name": "CHARISSE"
  "Reports To Position ID": "YQM000076"
}
...
```

Because of that your objects don't have a property `Postition ID`. Trying to create hashtable entries from these missing properties causes the errors you observed.

Change

```
$csvData = Import-Csv "C:\My.csv"
```

to

```
$csvData = Import-Csv "C:\My.csv" -Delimiter "`t"
```

and your code should behave as you expect.